# How to find collections where an selected object is linked to?

Tags: collections

I have an chair model and it is linked to multiple Collections. How to find what collections that the object is linked to ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least 3 solutions:

- If you select the object, go in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Collections*, you'll see the collections the object is part of:

[image]

- In the 3D view if you select the object and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> > *Collection*, it will display the collections the object is part of:

[image]

- If you select the object, in the *Outliner* you'll see an object icon enlighted next to the collections that contain it:

[image]

Comment: Thank, the little annoying thing with method #3 (outliner) is when i deselect the objects, the collection is still highlighted in outliner.

Comment: so maybe it's a change to suggest to Blender developers