# How do I reconcile this Duplicate Object?

Tags: objects, collections, outliner

I don't know how I got here...

Somewhere along the way in my project I have ended up with a duplicate of my main hero object, and I can't figure out how to delete the duplicate without deleting the original.  I also can't figure out how to recombine them into a single object.

I also can't drag the object out of the collection it is in, nor can I move the duplicate into that collection, or any other collection.

I've stripped down my project to include only the object in question.  I feel stupid, what am I missing here?

[PROJECT FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ch7mqa7eqj0iun/Duplicate%20Object%20Why.blend?dl=0)

[image]

Comment: Seems like a little bit broken file to me. First it acted strange, as it was selecting both objects simultaneously deleting or unlinking both objects at once as you described, but once I did something random, like switching on/off some filtering or sorting, it stopped acting like that, I could then select just one of those objects and unlink it. Then one of them disappeared. Btw it happens to me sometimes too, usually when I work with objects grouped by parenting.

Comment: The file isn't broken in any way, the object belongs to two collections simultaneously. There is nothing odd about it. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190880/how-to-find-collections-where-an-selected-object-is-linked-to

Comment: I know it's a stripped-down file, but you can actually right-click on the 'Collection' inside the Scene Collection in your uploade file and choose 'Unlink' and the Object will still remain in the Scene Collection so if you can move any other objects out of that collection in your full file you should be able to do the same without your object disappearing.

Comment: Than how to reproduce this behavior: https://ibb.co/mDC9Lqf ? As soon as I did anything random, it stopped acting like that and I was then able to select one or the other individually. But I wasn't able to return back to the state where both selects at once.

Comment: And "I can't figure out how to delete the duplicate without deleting the original." maybe refers to this:  https://ibb.co/Q6ynVGW

Comment: Thank you all for looking at this for me. The solution was as @DuarteFarrajotaRamos pointed out, all I had to do was go into the Collections tab in the Object Properties and uncheck the collection the object was tied to, which thusly removed the duplicate.  This is a very odd function of Blender, feels like some antiquated option that overly complicates the workflow... but then again Blender is nothing if not overcomplicated at times ;)